# Drag and drop a file on label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help, again

I can drag and drop a file or click on a basic input file on HTML5 and it'll work.
What I want is to be able to make that with a label, I can click on the label to add a file with a label for but I can't drag and drop a file on the label. I've tried to make it possible with that JavaScript over here but it didn't work, I've read some tutorials and I'm not sure of the code below.

```js
$(document).on('dragenter', '#image-event-label', function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #B8A1F5');
        return false;
    });
     
    $(document).on('dragover', '#image-event-label', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #B8A1F5');
        return false;
    });
     
    $(document).on('dragleave', '#image-event-label', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #422B7E');
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('drop', '#image-event-label', function(e) {
        if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
           if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
               e.preventDefault();
               e.stopPropagation();
               $(this).css('border', '1px solid #0F0');
               upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
           }  
        }
        else {
           $(this).css('border', '1px solid #422B7E');
        }
        return false;
    });

    function upload(files) {
        var f = files[0] ;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            $('#image-event').val(event.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);      
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="image-event" id="image-event-label">Import an image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image-event" style="display:none" id="image-event">
```

Thanks everybody in advance !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way, is to append your `input[type=file]` directly in your `<label>`, and to style this input in a way it covers all the label.

Doing so, you'll be able to drop files directly on the label, and the input's default behavior will take care of it, ultimately, no js is needed in this part:

```js
// only to show it did change
$('#image-event').on('change', function upload(evt) {
  console.log(this.files[0]);
});

// only to show where is the drop-zone:
$('#image-event-label').on('dragenter', function() {
  this.classList.add('dragged-over');
})
 .on('dragend drop dragexit dragleave', function() {
  this.classList.remove('dragged-over');
});
```

```css
#image-event {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#image-event-label {
  position: relative;
}

#image-event-label.dragged-over {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="image-event" id="image-event-label">
        Import an image
        <input type="file" name="image-event" id="image-event">
</label>
```

---

Now, note that it is actually now* possible to set the `.files` FileList of an `input[type=file]`, but you need to set it to an other FileList object, and fortunately, there is one available in the DataTransfer object that comes along the DropEvent:

```js
function handleDroppedFile(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // since we use jQuery we need to grab the originalEvent
  var dT = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
  var files = dT.files;
  if (files && files.length) {
    // we set our input's 'files' property
    $('#image-event')[0].files = files;
  }
}
$('#image-event-label').on({
    'drop': handleDroppedFile,
    'dragenter': function(e) { e.preventDefault(); },
    'dragover': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.classList.add('dragged-over');
    }
  })
  .on('dragleave dragexit', function() {
    this.classList.remove('dragged-over')
  });
```

```css
.dragged-over {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="image-event" id="image-event-label">
        Drop a file here
</label> <br><br>
<input type="file" name="image-event" id="image-event">
```

*IIRC, this is now supported in Chrome, Safari, latests Edge and latests Firefox. I don't think IE does support it though, so beware when using this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it tonight ! I put my post as resolved :)

Comment: `opacity: 0` is clever, I wish I had thought of this.  No need to use external library for basic upload!